# Giving admin users flexibility on defining calculation formula for web app... is it a good idea?

Tags: python, django, security

I'm designing a Django project, for which I'd like to give administrators flexibility on defining certain calculation formulas.

Although I can assume that admins won't <strike>do stupid things</strike> break the system by defining unappropriate formulas, I'm feeling very uncomfortable on the ways this freedom can be implemented:

1. Saving the code of the formula to the database, fetch it when the formula is needed and apply it.
2. Allowing admin users to write Python modules, save them to a preset location, save the module and function name in the database, fetch it when the formula is needed and apply it.

Both ways look like huge security holes to the system, and I'd like to avoid that at all costs... but the only way I can think to prevent code injection attacks (is that the appropriate name?) is:

- Close the system: No user can define formulas, and
- If an admin needs to apply a custom formula, then (s)he would need to ask the system administrator to write, test and implement it.

So, in short: Is there a way to give a little group of users (administrators) the  freedom (and power) to define custom functions that would be applied under certain conditions? If there is a way: how can it be implemented in a safe maner?

---

Some context:

- This project will be a prototype: It will be used for experiments.
- All formulas would be written in Python.
- The formulas that will be written would be used to calculate payments.
- After defining the formulas, I'd like to write some automated tests that will validate the formula.
- The parameters for the formula will be limited to certain values stored in the database.
- Ideally, I'd like the custom formulas to be sandboxed before definitive implementation, which would need to be approved by some one (system administrator) before it gets out to production.

Comment: Is it an option to have the formulas written in a different language that is not python and only has a controlled set of operations available? Actually executing code from external services in an unsecured environment is indeed a risk as you already pointed out. At least it should be sandboxed service with limited rights that does the evaluation.

Comment: @trixn I'm open to the option of using a different language for functions... but, if possible, I'd like to stick to Python (for simplicity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that python is mandatory as a language for the formulas I'd go with running each formula in an unprivileged docker container that is limited in

- io access
- network access
- memory and cpu usage
- total time to run (probably only a few seconds)
- other reasonable measures to prevent abusive usage of system resources

and throw that container away after every calculation.

The main security risks of that would be:

- misconfiguration of the container
- zero-day exploits of bugs in the kernel (as it is shared with the host system in docker)

There are a number of projects that use that concept, e.g. [epicbox](https://github.com/StepicOrg/epicbox) but I have no idea of how reliable they are.